# How to solve "buyTickets" class

Tags: java

Need help solving class for a project.
New variables cannot be introduced.
There are ticket types U, L and F (Upper, Lower, Floor)
Test program tests for multiple tickets.
Values for these:

```
private static final double PRICE_UPPER_TICKET = 29.9;
private static final double PRICE_LOWER_TICKET = 99.0;
private static final double PRICE_FLOOR_TICKET = 180.0;
private static int TOTAL_NUMBER_FLOOR_TICKETS= 400;
private static int TOTAL_NUMBER_LOWER_TICKETS= 300;
private static int TOTAL_NUMBER_UPPER_TICKETS= 300;

public void buyTickets (char ticketType, int numTickets, double pmt)
```

- For now, assume numTickets and pmt contain positive int values
- If there are available number of tickets (numTickets) in the specific section/ticket type that you want to buy.
- Calculate the amount due based on the ticket type and number of tickets
- If the payment, entered as input parameter, is large enough to pay for the tickets: 1) add the amount due to total sales, 2) decrease the number of tickets available for the specific section and 3) display the results of the transaction.
- If the payment, entered as input parameter, is not enough to pay for the tickets: print a message indicating the problem with the amount. The client cannot buy the tickets.

Tried many if statements. Below is my code.

```
if  ('L' < numTickets){
            if(pmt < PRICE_LOWER_TICKET * numTickets){
                System.out.println("Insuffient funds");
            }
            pmt = PRICE_LOWER_TICKET * numTickets;
            totalSales = pmt + totalSales;
            System.out.println(pmt);
        }
       }
```

Just spitting out 0.

Comment: What does this 'L' < numTickets mean? Why is it written?

Comment: Perhaps showing your whole attempt might give us more insight on how you're approaching it (also comments help both us and yourself). Also I'm not quite sure how `if('L' < numTickets)` is supposed to tell you if the ticket type is "Lower Floor"

Comment: It's not going to tell that ticket is of lower type. L has ascii value of 76, so if numTickets is 76 or less than 76 it will never go inside the if condition.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the ticket type char first off to know which price and which total tickets variable to use (eg ticketType == 'L' will mean use lower tickets price and total)  then check their payment is greater than the ticketprice * numTickets for that ticket area AND check the number of tickets < the total tickets available for that area. Hope this helps

Comment: Nice code :)   But if we do their homework for them, they'll never learn anything - so we should guide rather than provide.   see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions